# How to disable image popup in magento

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.5.0.1 for one of my websites. In that, whenever a person mouseovers an image in grid view or list view, a bigger image window pop ups. Is there a way i can disable this and also get rid of the zooming functionality in product views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not core Magento functionality so there will be a 3rd party extension installed or perhaps even more simply, additional JavaScript and CSS files are being loaded.  Since i have no way of knowing any more about your setup, i can only provide some general help...

**3rd party extension**

If the extensions sole purpose is to provide zoom functionality in the product list block then I would simply disable or remove it completely.  If it offers other features beyond product zoom that you require then you may need to adjust the module to meet your needs.

If you do not know the modules name, have a look in the source code under app/etc/modules as a starting point.  In here you will see a list xml files for all installed modules.  If you can identify the module you can disable it by editing the active node in xml file:

From:

```
<active>true</active>
```

To:

```
<active>false</active>
```

then clear your cache.

If you cannot identify it from there, have a look through the admin section for some clues - most modules will provide some configuration options.

**Additional JS and CSS files being loaded**

If there are simply some extra JS and CSS files being loaded in order to provide this functionality.  You will have to look through your layout.xml files in your theme:

`app/design/your_package/your_theme/layout`

There are a few different of ways to include js and css files so you would be looking for something similar to one of the following:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>js/yourjs.js</script></action>

<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>js/yourjs.js</name></action>

<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/yourjs.js</name></action>
```

If you can find the node responsible for including the js then simply remove it.

Comment: It's MagicZoomPlus....I dont know much about magento....will read into your solution and try to see if i m able to fix this...thanks for the reply....

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay - did you have any luck with this?

Comment: not really...I am able to remove the zooming on product details page after uninstalling the extension. But, the image-popup on category views is still dere

Answer (score 3):

Go to template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

Find this code:

```
<a onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>', 'gallery', 'width=520,height=480,left=50,top=50,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="#">
<img id="image" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(250,250); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
</a>
```

And replace it with this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName();?>" onclick="$('image').src = this.href; return false;"> <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
```

Answer (score -3):

Thank you. It's very useful code.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName();?>" onclick="$('image').src = this.href; return false;"> 
     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
</a>
```